# SFTP through php exec()

Tags: php, exec, sftp

Is it possible to use SFTP linux command, using php exec() or system() function?

I try this:

```
exec('sftp '.$user.'@'.$server.' && '.$pass.' && get '.$path1.' '.$path2.');
```

but it doesnt work. Guess because of login at least)

Also tried to split execs, still its useless:

```
exec('sftp root@'.$server);
exec($pass);
exec('get '.$path1.' '.$path2);
```

maybe there is any inline command or another syntaxis for this?

And yes, i want to use SFTP, no i dont wanna use libraries.

Also if there is some way to make it work with special bash or etc file, that i can run with exec() it would be nice too.

Comment: You could use [passwordless login](https://www.google.com/search?q=sftp+passwordless+login&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

Comment: Why do you want to use `sftp` in the first place? + Also note that `sftp user@server && get` is wrong too. That cannot work. Did you even try that on command-line (in shell)?

Comment: You obviously have no idea how shell works, so why do you even take that route? - Use some native PHP SFTP library instead!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i tried this in shell ofc. In shell i do it step by step. And the question is how to do the same with php exec(). I know how shell works, i just dont know how to use correctly php function here.

Comment: No you didn't try it in shell. If you did, you would knew that `sftp user@server && get` does not work. And you do not know how shell works. If you knew, you would know that `exec('sftp root@'.$server);` and `exec('get '.$path1.' '.$path2);` is even greater nonsense than the `sftp user@server && get`.

Comment: Did you follow the link in my previous comment? It shows a working way to pass commands to `sftp` the way you need to do in PHP `exec`. So, how can you claim, that I'm not trying to help? - Do you still insist on `sftp user@server && get` working in shell? Because it clearly does not!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I said i did the same in shell, but i said 'step-by-step', mean that first line i used 'sftp' to connect as root, after that i typed pass in dialog, and after i typed 'get ...' to get file from remote server. That "sftp && get" I used for example, because I was trying to find a way how to use different commands inline. And ofc I know it doesnt work. I saw the thread u lnked in prev post before i started this one. Didnt help me... Tried to type it down different ways

Comment: And that clearly indicates, that you do not know, how shell works! And my linked answer shows you the way! And yet you dare to call me an "idiot"!

Comment: *"Didnt help me... Tried to type it down different ways"* - What ways? Show us! *"Didn't help me"* doesn't help us helping you! - But, I'm stopping here helping you, for your behavior. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
system('sshpass -p '.$pass.' sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@'.$server.':'.$path.' '.$path, $D);
```